# How do I iterate over *args when passing a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, statistics

I have written the following function, which takes in any number of columns of a dataframe as a list and then prints the median of the specified columns:

```
def calculate_median(dataframe, *args, *kwargs):
    print("Median of columns: ")
    for colname in args or kwargs.values():
        median_of_column = np.median(dataframe[colname])
        print(f"{median_of_column}", sep="\n")
    return colname
```

So, if I have the following list of columns within the dataframe:

```
colnames = ['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C', 'Col D']
```

The issue I am having is that the interpreter is taking the *entire* list as a whole parameter and displaying the median of *only* the first column (Col A).

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: @interjay - 

```median_of_df_columns = calculate_median(df, colnames) # df has been imported before```

Comment: Why are you using varargs (`*args`) then instead of a normal parameter? Your use of `kwargs` seems wrong as well.

Comment: Using `*args` in a parameter does not mean that Python will *unpack* arguments passed into it. It only means it will *pack* arguments received. If you want to unpack a list to arguments, use ``*`` in the call. If you want to unpack something only to then pack it again, just skip unpack/pack'ing entirely and pass/receive it as a plain argument/parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling your function like this:

```
df = ...
colname = calculate_median(df, colnames)
```

You need to call it like this instead:

```
df = ...
colname = calculate_median(df, *colnames)
```

The `*args` parameter means "any number of non-keyword (ie unnamed) arguments".  If you just pass a list (`colnames`), that's a single argument, not multiple arguments.  Passing `*colnames` instead means "unpack this list and use the items in it as arguments".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing an asterisk on `*kwargs`. Your function signature should be:

```
def calculate_mean(dataframe, *args, **kwargs):
```

Second, I'm not sure that your for-loop does what you think it does. Currently it would iterate over `args` and only iterate over `kwargs.values()` in case args is `None` or empty. If you want to always iterate over both, you could convert `kwargs.values()` to a tuple, so that it has the same type as `args` and then concatenate them:

```
for colname in args + tuple(kwargs.values()):
```

Then you would call your function like this:

```
calculate_mean('Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C', 'Col D')
```

or if you have a list:

```
colnames = ['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C', 'Col D']
```

and you want to call the function with each member of the list as an arg, you need to unpack the list by using asterisk when you call the function:

```
calculate_mean(*colnames)
```

Comment: I don't see the value in iterating over `kwargs.values` while ignoring the keys in the first place.

Comment: @interjay Neither do I, but as I understood it, that was what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: I don't think OP knows exactly what they're trying to do. They probably don't understand what `**kwargs` does. This is not a criticism of your answer as there's not much that can be done until OP clarifies.

Comment: @interjay Yes after reading the question again, I suspect that you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `*df.columns` as `*args` parameter to get the required result. Becaues passing only `df.columns` will not unpack the values of columns.

And I don't understand why you need `*kwargs`  parameter.

Answer (score -2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "b": [11, 22, 33, 44, 55], "c": [111, 222, 333, 444, 555]})
print(df)

# error: need double *
def calculate_median(dataframe, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Median of columns: ")
    for colname in args or kwargs.values():
        median_of_column = np.median(dataframe[colname])
        print(f"{median_of_column}", sep="\n")
    return colname
# get dataframe column names 
colnames= df.columns.values
print(f"colnames type={type(colnames)}")
print(f"colnames values={colnames}")
# call function
calculate_median(df, *colnames)
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what you changed and why, instead of making us play "find the differences".